# Updates Require Authentication

Tags: updates, authentication

My Update Manager in Ubuntu 12.04 pops up this message while installing updates: '*Requires installation of untrusted packages. The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources*'. In Details: '*gnome-control-center gnome-control-center -data libgnome-control-center*'

How to solve the problem?

Thankyou. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have missing keys, this can easily be solved but first you need to run update to see what the missing key is.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You will now get an error saying that some public key is not available. To add it just run:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com <key>
```

Replace  with the key that the error when you did apt-get update showed. Example, Ubuntu default repositories key is 437D05B5

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 437D05B5
```